# Necessary and sufficient conditions for affine maps to coincide on their respective domains

Tags: linear-algebra, social-choice

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a set of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$ let there be an affine linear map $f_A\colon \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, assume that for any $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ and $v\in A\cap B$, it is $f_A(v)=f_B(v)$ (*).

I am interested in finding a necessary and sufficient condition on $\mathcal{A}$ such that for all choices of functions $(f_A)_{A\in\mathcal{A}}$ satisfying (*), there is an affine map $g$ such that
$$g(v) = f_A(v) \text{ for all }A\in\mathcal{A}\text{ and }v\in A.\quad (1)$$

Motivation: this question arises in decision theory. One can think of the points in $A\in\mathcal{A}$ as utilities individuals could get under a certain condition, and the functions $f_A$ as aggregating these utilities into a social welfare function. There are results that for each of the sets $A\in\mathcal{A}$, the social welfare function is an affine linear function $f_A$ on the individual utilities. Moreover, I know that for two different sets, the functions need to coincide on their intersection. I now want to derive a necessary and sufficient condition for the social welfare function to be representable by one affine linear function of individual utilities for all sets in $\mathcal{A}$. I also know that all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ must be convex, although I haven't used that fact yet.

My own work: It is easy to find a counter-example that shows that some condition is needed. E.g., take two sets $A,B$ which are disjoint and both have full dimensionality in $\mathbb{R}^n$, two differing functions $f_A\neq f_B$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{A,B\}$.

As a means to finding such a condition I tried introducing sets $\Phi(A,B)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ which include all points on which $f_A$ and $f_B$ must coincide. For instance,  it is $f_A=f_B$ on $\mathrm{aff}(A\cap B)$ (where aff denotes the affine span) and hence $\mathrm{aff}(A\cap B)\subseteq\Phi(A,B)$. Also, $\Phi(A,B)\cap\Phi(B,C)\subseteq\Phi(A,C)$ for $A,B,C\in\mathcal{A}$, and $\Phi(A,B)$ is always an affine span.

A sufficient condition would be if for any strict subset $\mathcal{G}\subsetneq\mathcal{A}$, there is a condition $A\in\mathcal{A}\setminus\mathcal{G}$ with
$$\mathrm{aff}(A)\cap\mathrm{aff}\left(\bigcup_{G\in\mathcal{G}}G\right)\subseteq \mathrm{aff}\left(\bigcup_{G\in\mathcal{G}}\Phi(A,G)\right).$$

Then we can inductively choose some function $g$ which fulfills (1) on $\mathcal{A}$ (or via some other method if $\mathcal{A}$ is uncountable). To illustrate the idea, assume there is such a function $g$ which works for a subset $\mathcal{G}\subsetneq \mathcal{A}$. Then the condition provides a set $A$ such that $g$ and $f_A$ are equal on $\mathrm{aff}(A)\cap\mathrm{aff}(\bigcup_{G\in\mathcal{G}}G)$. Hence, we can choose a new function $g'$ which equals both $f_A$ and $g$ on this set and extend this function as equal to $f_A$ on $\mathrm{aff}(A)$ and equal to $g$ on $\mathrm{aff}(\bigcup_{G\in\mathcal{G}}G)$. Then $g'$ fulfills (1) for $\mathcal{G}\cup\{A\}$.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a sufficient condition which is also necessary or to prove that the above condition is necessary.

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}$ contains a convex set $A$ with non-empty interior, then (1) is satisfied iff  $g \Doteq f_A$ coincide with $f_B$ on $B$ for every $B$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: If every convex set $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$ has empty interior, then we may focus on the case $n = 1$ first. Here (1) is satisfied if and only if the points $(x_A, f_A(x_A))$ with $A = \{x_A\}$ lie on a same line (In particular, you have examples where all $\text{aff}(A)$ and all $f_A(\mathbb{R})$ are pariwise disjoint and (1) holds true). These two equivalences are rather tautological and I fail to see what kind of useful characterization one could derive in general.

Comment: Thanks, Luc Guyot! I am especially interested in conditions that do not involve the $f_A$ directly, as these are the objects I would like to prove something about, using only constraints on $\mathcal{A}$ (and the assumptions outlined in the first paragraph).
I would be very happy about either necessary and sufficient constraints on $\mathcal{A}$ (no matter how involved or unintuitive) or maybe also about very simple and (as weak as possible) sufficient constraints. An example of a simple and sufficient one would be if the intersection of any two sets in $\mathcal{A}$ has a non-empty interior.

Comment: Dear Johannes, thanks for your explanations. If I understand your question correctly, then there is **no condition on $\mathcal{A}$**, and on $\mathcal{A}$ only, which is equivalent to $(1)$.
The reason is simple, and somehow you already mentioned it: you can find a set $\mathcal{A}$ for which $(1)$ holds true for some choice of the functions $f_A$ but doesn't for a different choice. Take your example with $\mathcal{A} = \{A, B\}$ or take $n = 1$ and $\mathcal{A} = \{\{0\}, \{1\}, \{2\}\}$.

Comment: About sufficient conditions, this is a game we can play. But it would be even more interesting if you could specify what is a *useful*, *nice* or *satisfying* condition for you. What are we trying to optimize? How could these conditions be reused with some benefits for you?

Comment: Dear Luc, thanks again for your insightful comments. This made me realize that I incorrectly stated what I was interested in. I am actually interested in a condition such that for all choices of functions $f_A$ that adhere to (\*) (the condition in the first paragraph), there is an affine map $g$ which fulfills (1). So the condition counts as necessary for me if it is the case that if it is violated by the $\mathcal{A}$, then there is at least one assignment of functions $f_A$ (consistent with (*)) such that there is no affine map $g$ which fulfills (1).

Comment: I think I understand it correctly now. (I posted a long comment as a partial answer). Well, I hope so. I am still confused by the discussion on the sets $\Phi(A, B) = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n \, \vert \, f_A(v) = f_B(v) \}$. They do involve the functions $f_A$. So how could your condition be a valid candidate in the sense of your last comment? Unless $\Phi(A, B)$ is an alias for $\text{aff}(A \cap B)$?

Comment: Regarding the functions $\Phi$: In my draft, I construct a function $\Phi$ which yields what I believe to be exactly the sets $\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid f_A(v)=f_B(v)\text{ for all functions }f_A,f_B\text{ in agreement with }(*)\}$. I require that for all $A,B,C\in\mathcal{A}$, it is $\Phi(A,B)\supseteq\text{aff}(A\cap B)$, it is $\Phi(A,B)\cap \Phi(B,C)\subseteq \Phi(A,C)$, and $\Phi(A,B)$ is always an affine space. I think a unique function $\Phi$ mapping pairs of sets to the minimal (w.r.t. set inclusion) set such that all of these properties are fulfilled can easily be shown to exist.

Comment: $\Phi(A, B) = \bigcap_{f_A, f_B} \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n \, \vert \, f_A(v) = f_B(v)\}$ where the functions are (*)-compatible?

Comment: Great! That looks to me like a much better way to construct these sets. Somehow I didn't come up with this before.

Comment: Maybe a slight shortcoming of this would be that it would not be very constructive, so the definition does not tell us much about what the sets in $\mathcal{A}$ have to look like. So in terms of what I look for in a sufficient condition, I think it would be nice if it was simple to state, and I would prefer it if the condition gave some insight into what $\mathcal{A}$ must look like, i.e., if it was relatively concrete and not too hard to check. My proposed construction already fails somewhat on this front.

Comment: I am afraid that $\Phi(A, B)$ is just another name for $\text{aff}(A \cap B)$. This is easily seen in dimension $2$. For your question, the case $n = 1$ is easy to sort out (this could appear in your discussion). But $n = 2$ is much more challenging and many interesting configurations are admissible (I am trying to think about it in terms of graphs or hypergraphs).

Comment: Hmm, I thought this was not always the case. For instance, take $A,B,C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ sets with nonempty interior such that $A\cap C = \emptyset$ but $A\cap B$ and $B\cap C$ both also have nonempty interior. Then for all functions $f_A,f_B,f_C$, for (*) to be satisfied it must be $f_A=f_B$ and $f_B=f_C$, both on the entire space. Hence, $f_A=f_C$, so $\Phi(A,C)=\mathbb{R}^2$. But $\mathrm{aff}(A\cap C) = \mathrm{aff}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ by assumption. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for making the effort and thinking about this! I'm happy to read anything you have and try to understand it myself, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100596/discussion-between-luc-guyot-and-johannes-treutlein).